# Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?

Tags: python

Привет. Читаю книгу A Byte of Python. Там на 32й странице http://wombat.org.ua/AByteOfPython/AByteofPythonRussian-2.01.pdf
создается своя команда helloworld и с помощью нее можно вызывать файл helloworld.py из любого места. К примеру просто py/helloworld.py у меня получается запускать, а вот как сделать свою команду не пойму. Знаю есть alies, но в книге как-то иначе делается. Кто подскажет как повторить пример? И чем отличается от alies?

Comment: вы пока код пишите, к концу книги всё поймёте - не отвлекайтесь на пустяки

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?

Также как и любую другую программу:

- файл должен быть в одной из директорий, указанной в `$PATH`

  ```
  $ echo $PATH
  ```
- файл должен быть исполняемым

  ```
  $ chmod +x путь/к/helloworld.py
  ```
- файл должен содержать корректную shebang строку на самом верху, например:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  ```

Если `~/bin` директория находится в `$PATH`, то можно symlink создать:

```
$ ln -s /полный/путь/к/helloworld.py ~/bin/helloworld
```

После этого можно запускать `helloworld` из любой директории:

```
$ helloworld
```

---

В качестве альтернативы, чтобы автоматически создать исполняемый файл в пути из `helloworld.py` можно использовать `setup.py` файл:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='helloworld',
    version='0.1',
    py_modules=['helloworld'],
    entry_points='''
        [console_scripts]
        helloworld=helloworld:main
    ''',
)
```

Код для запуска следует в `main()` функцию поместить.

Чтобы инсталлировать скрипт (из директории с `setup.py`):

```
$ python -m pip install .
```

Если вы не используете virtualenv, тогда можно добавить `--user` опцию, чтобы локально для текущего пользователя поставить:

```
$ python -m pip install . --user
```

нужно добавить `~/.local/bin` в путь (`$PATH` переменная окружения) в этом случае.

После этого можно запускать `helloworld` из любой директории:

```
$ helloworld
```

---

> А в чем отличие этого подхода от alies?

Проще сказать что общее: `alias` (псевдоним) также как и другие подходы позволяет, набирая строку, например: `helloworld`, запустить желаемую команду. `alias` — это функциональность оболочки (такой как `bash`). Как symlink так и явная установка с помощью `setup.py`, приведённые в ответе, не требуют оболочку, чтобы потом запускать команду, например, можно из Питона запустить `rc = subprocess.call('helloworld')`.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37753/discussion-on-answer-by-jfs----python-----ubuntu).

Comment: @jfs This link cannot be used because its target “/python/hello.py” doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ chmod a+x helloworld.py
```

После этого мы можем запускать программу напрямую, потому что наша операционная система запустит /usr/bin/env, который, в свою очередь, найдёт Python 3, а значит,
сможет запустить наш файл.

```
$ ./helloworld.py
```

Привет, Мир!

Comment: Спасибо. Это я как раз сделал)

Answer (score 1):

Вам необходимо добавить путь к каталогу с Вашим скриптом в переменную окружения PATH:

```
PATH=$PATH:/path/to/your/dir
```