# Запуск програмы с терминала

Tags: python, macos, python-3.5

Как запустить программу которая написана в Python 3.5 через терминал в mac os?

Comment: [Такой же вопрос, но для Ubuntu (ответы похожи)](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507591/23044)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Запустите терминал
2) Перейдите к папке с файлом, выполнив следующую команду:

```
cd <путь/к/запускаемому/файлу/>
```

3) Теперь запускаем файл следующей командой:

```
python3 <имя_файла>.py
```

4) Подождите пока завершится выполнение файла
5) Закройте терминал :)

P.S. "< >" писать не надо
P.S.S. Если надо без python3 используйте псевдонимы.
Псевдонимы в Unix имеют следующий синтаксис: 
     `alias <псевдоним> = '<команда>'`

В вашем случае команда будет выглядеть вот так: 
    `alias <имя файла> = 'python3 <имя файла>'`

Созданный таким образом псевдоним будет работать до завершения сессии.
Для создания постоянных псевдонимов в UNIX рекомендуется использовать файл ~/.bash_aliases, однако в Mac OS X данный файл не обрабатывается. Поэтому их можно добавить в файл ~/.bash_profile. 
 
 
Подробнее о псевдонимах здесь:osxh.ru/terminal/command/alias

Comment: а без пайтон3 можно както?

Comment: Эм. Как вы собираетесь запускать программу написанную на python3 без python3? Python - интерпретатор, он выполняет код сразу же, без компиляции. Если очень уж приспичило, можно скомпилировать через cx_freeze.

Comment: я имел введу без 'python3' а не без интерпретатора)интересовался возможно ли вписать только имя файла

Comment: Используйте псевдонимы. Синтаксис: `alias <псевдоним> = '<команда>'`. Для создания постоянных псевдонимов в UNIX рекомендуется использовать файл ~/.bash_aliases, однако в Mac OS X данный файл не обрабатывается. Поэтому их можно добавить в файл ~/.bash_profile. Подробнее здесь:http://osxh.ru/terminal/command/alias

Answer (score 0):

Заходишь в папку, в которой лежит файл, через терминал и вводишь:

```
python3 name_file.py
```

Comment: а в папку как зайти?и нельзя открить файл непосредственно только испозовав терминал как програму?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: командой ls можно вывести

Comment: командой `pwd` можно знать путь, где вы сейчас находитесь.
команда`ls` выводит список файлов и папок в этой дериктории.
для переходя в другую директорию нужно использовать команду `cd`  ‘имя_папки’
имя без кавычек. когда будите в нужной папке тогда команда: `python3 file_name.py`