# Как вывести в терминале пользователя, самого нагруженного процесса?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

Как вывести в терминале пользователя, самого нагруженного процесса?

**Пробовал вот так:**  `ps -eo %u | sort -nr -k 1| head -1`
Отображает самый большой (по числу) Pid  пользователя.

Подскажите, как вывести именно пользователя. Например имеется самый высокий процесс пользователя vasya  у которого mem или cpu загружена на 70%.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вопрос интересный.

Если, конечно, я его правильно понял, и ответ не сводится к простому запуску

```
top
```

(и при необходимости переключению сортировки клавишей <kbd>M</kbd>).

## Давайте сначала разберемся с памятью,

это проще:

```
$ ps axh -o user --sort -vsize | head -n 1
tomcat
```

Эта команда выведет имя пользователя, который использует больше всего памяти (в данном случае им оказался `tomcat`). Если хотите подробностей, добавьте колонок: `-o user,vsize,cmd`.

Ключи:

- `ax` - показать все процессы.
- `h` - не показывать заголовки.
- `-o user` - формат вывода.
- `--sort -vsize` - сортировка по занимаемой памяти по убыванию (убывание задается знаком `-` перед `vsize`).

## Теперь интересное - CPU

Хотелось бы по аналогии использовать `ps --sort cpu`. Однако man гласит:

> CPU usage is currently expressed as the percentage of time spent running during the entire lifetime of a process.  This is not ideal,

и это правда не то, что нам нужно, нам-то нужно понять, какой процесс грузит больше всего **сейчас**.

А что с командой `top`? У нее есть batch mode, казалось бы, `top -b -n 1 | head` и проблема решена. Однако практика показывает, что при таком запуске top показывает далеко не самую точную информацию. Например, самым тяжелым процессом он может показать самого себя.

Чтобы данные были более достоверны, top нужно поработать некоторое время.

И вот тут приходит решение. Запустим top на несколько итераций, а самый тяжелый процесс возьмем из последней. На помощь призовем `awk`.

Скрипт на awk:

### max-user.awk

```
    # инициализация
    BEGIN { START=999 ; COUNT = 0 }

    # Как только видим Tasks в начале строки, понимаем,
    # что top выодит новую порцию данных.
    # Первая строка с процессом находится на 6 строк дальше.
    /^Tasks/ { START = NR + 6 }

    # 7-я строка - это заголовок. Выведем для красоты.
    NR == 7 { print }

    # Наконец-то строка с нашим процессом. Посчитаем итерацию
    # и выведем текущее состояние.
    NR == START { COUNT++; print }

    # Прошло 3 итерации, достаточно.
    COUNT == 3 { exit }
```

Запускать так:

```
$ top -b -n 10 -d 1 | awk -f max-user.awk

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
16235 cronfy    20   0   43216   3828   3196 R  12,5  0,1   0:00.02 top
 3070 olenka    20   0 4640760 997152  39036 S   3,0 13,1  24:59.97 java
 5099 olenka    20   0  859700 135380  70324 S   2,9  1,8  10:45.65 chrome
```

В **последней строке** (не в первой!) видим самый грузящий процесс. Получить имя пользователя можно так:

```
$ top -b -n 10 -d 1 | awk -f max-user.awk | awk 'END { print $2 }'
root
```

Ключи top:

- `-b` - неинтерактивный режим.
- `-n 10` - количество итераций. Можно поставить много, в любом случае выполнение будет прерывать awk.
- `-d 1` - задержка между итерациями.

Comment: Очень Вам благодарен! Спасибо Вам!

Answer (score 3):

Вот на Питоне кросс-платформенный вариант:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import psutil

for process in psutil.process_iter(): process.cpu_percent()  # ignore
time.sleep(1)  # averaging interval in seconds
print(max(psutil.process_iter(), key=psutil.Process.cpu_percent).username())
```

Скрипт:

1. перебирает все запущенные процессы и вызывает `cpu_percent()`, чтобы обозначить время, с которого статистика будет считаться (возвращаемое значение первого вызова бессмысленно)
2. спит `1` секунду — время, по которому утилизация CPU усредняется для каждого процесса. Поправьте для своих нужд.
3. находит процесс с наибольшей долей CPU за прошедшее (одна секунда) время и печатает соответствующее имя пользователя.

Для работы необходимо [поставить `psutil`](https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil/blob/master/INSTALL.rst) зависимость, к примеру, на Ubuntu:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-psutil
```

Или если не хочется трогать систему, то только для текущего пользователя можно поставить:

```
$ pip install --user psutil
```

См. [Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507591/23044)