# Ubuntu. Команда для отображения работоспособных процессов и самых прожорливых?

Tags: ubuntu, unix, администрирование

Всем привет, подскажите, пожалуйста, какими командами можно узнать самый прожорливый процесс который потребляет больше всего ресурсов ЦП.

Для вывода всех процессов которые имеют статус "работоспособный" можно использовать команду `ps aux | grep ^root` или `ps -U root` у них же нет особой разницы вывода?

Заранее благодарен.

Comment: связанный вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/629374/23044

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если брать на примере ps c выводом в файл

Вывод в файл первые 5 процессов "самых прожорливых" по ЦП

```
ps -aux | sort -n -r -k 3 | head -n 5 >> ~/rezult.txt
```

Вывод в файл первые 5 процессов "самых прожорливых" по памяти

```
ps -aux | sort -n -r -k 4 | head -n 5 >> ~/rezult.txt
```

5 - количество

3 или 4 - столбец по которому сортировать, соответсвенно можно отсортировать вывод по любому столбцу данных

~/rezult.txt - в какой файл писать, в данном варианте файл будет создан в Вашей домашней директории

Answer (score 2):

```
$ htop

F6 (SortBy) -> PERCENT_CPU
```

Если нужно дальше работать с данными:

```
ps haux --sort=-pcpu | head -n 1 > ~/жирный_процесс.txt
```

Comment: А если эту информацию я желаю записать в файл тогда как правильно записать?