# Как загрузить и запустить файлы python на VDS с Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu

Привет, не могу найти информацию в интернете - как запустить свой питон-файл на VDS с Ubuntu?

Все руководства говорят о том как установить питон, создать и запустить файл. Но если сам файл у меня уже готов? подскажите как загрузить его на сервер и запустить. спасибо

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как запускать файл Python из любого места в Ubuntu?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/507591/23044)

Answer (score 1):

запустить:

```
$ python /путь/к/скрипту
```

скопировать:

```
$ scp /локальный/путь/к/скрипту пользователь@сервер:/удалённый/путь/к/скрипту
```

а можно запустить и не сохраняя на сервере:

```
$ cat /локальный/путь/к/скрипту | ssh пользователь@сервер python -
```